# Wave equation with $u(x,0)=\sin^{3}x$ initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Problem def.: Solve the wave problem in a form of a Fourier series

PDE: $u_{tt}=3u_{xx}$

BCs: $u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0$

ICs: $u(x,0)=\sin^{3}x,\:u_{t}(x,0)=0,\qquad0<x<\pi$

My solution:

Using separation of variables and BCs, general solution to the PDE
is:

$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[A_{n}sin(n\sqrt{3}t)+B_{n}cos(n\sqrt{3}t)]sin(nx)$,
where $n=1,2,3,...$

To satisfy ICs:

$u_{t}(x,0)=0=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{3}nA_{n}sin(nx)\quad\Rightarrow A_{n}=0$

$u(x,0)=\sin^{3}x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}sin(nx)$

Therefore, the final solution is:

$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[B_{n}cos(n\sqrt{3}t)]sin(nx)$, where
$n=1,2,3,...$

$B_{n}=\frac{2}{\pi}\intop_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{3}(x)\sin(nx)dx$

Now my questions are:

1. Is this solution correct?
2. Is it acceptable to leave $B_n$ in this form (without solving the integral)?
3. I have played with Mathematica trying to solve the integral for $B_n$,
   and using trial and error determined that 'only' n=1 and n=3 produce
   $B_n$ that is not zero. More specifically: $B_{1}=3/4$ and $B_{3}=-1/4$.
   Is there an easy way to do this analytically?

Comment: Is the fourier series necessary because without it the answer is very easy

Comment: Yes, I believe that the Fourier series is desired - however, I am not 100% sure. What would be your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that $sin^3x=\frac {3sinx-sin3x}{4}$ and try comparing coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

- $$\sin^3x=\frac{3 \sin{x}}{4}-\frac{\sin 3 x}{4}$$
- Let $u_1$ solution of
  $$u_{tt}=3u_{xx},\\u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0,\\u(x,0)=\frac{3 \sin{x}}{4},\:u_{t}(x,0)=0,$$
  Let $u_2$ solution of
  $$u_{tt}=3u_{xx},\\u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0,\\u(x,0)=-\frac{\sin{3x}}{4},\:u_{t}(x,0)=0,$$
  Then $u=u_1+u_2$ is final solution.
- Solution of the first problem we seek in form
  $u=v(t)\sin(x)$. Substituting this expression
  of the solution in equation and initial conditions we obtain ode
  $$v''(t)=-3v(t),\;v(0)=\frac34,\;v'(0)=0,\\ \Rightarrow \quad v(t)=\frac{3 \cos{\left( \sqrt{3} t\right) }}{4},\\u_1=\frac{3 \cos{\left( \sqrt{3} t\right) } \sin{(x)}}{4}$$
- Solution of the second problem we seek in form
  $u=v(t)\sin(3x)$. Substituting this expression
  of the solution in equation and initial conditions we obtain ode
  $$v''(t)=-27v(t),\;v(0)=-\frac14,\;v'(0)=0,\\ \Rightarrow \quad v(t)=-\frac{\cos{\left( 3\sqrt{3} t\right) }}{4},\\u_2=-\frac{\cos{\left( 3\sqrt{3} t\right) } \sin{(3x)}}{4}$$
- Final solution is
  $$u=u_1+u_2=\frac{3\cos{\left(\sqrt{3} t\right) } \sin{(x)}}{4}-\frac{\cos{\left(3 \sqrt{3} t\right) } \sin{(3x)}}{4}$$